# remove double spaces, new line and break in php

Tags: php

I have a stream of characters, a sentence or a paragraph, which may have extra spaces in two words or even tabs or line feeds, how can I remove all these and substitute them by a single whitespace

### here is my code

```
$str = "a   bc
d e       f";

output : a bc de f
```

Comment: take a look at `preg_replace()` I think this will solve your problems. I do not know the actual regex for the function though. You will have to look that up.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$str);
```